# Don't store keys with empty string values in mongodb document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multipartform-data

i would like to store a post as a document in mongodb. I’m using mongoose for modelling and the content is created by a user using a form. The content of the form is append to FormData and sending to server. This works so far. The only issue is, that empty fields, that are appended as empty strings in the req.body will be stored in the document. The minimalize-property of my dataschema is already set true …

```
const post = req.body;
await Post.create(post);
```

req.body looks like:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  image: '',
  title: 'hi',
  subtitle: '',
  category: 'Jobs',
  tags: '',
  text: '',
  contactperson: '',
  contact: '',
  author: 'Felicia',
  expires: '2022-08-06'
}
```

My document looks exactly the same, but i would like to make it look like this:

```
{
  title: 'hi',
  category: 'Jobs',
  author: 'Felicia',
  expires: '2022-08-06'
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can check for keys containing empty string values and remove them before storing the object in MongoDB - do that before calling `Post.create(post)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build an object by filtering the `req.body` empty properties with:

```
const post = {};
for (const key in req.body) {
    const value = req.body[key];
    if (value && value !== '') {
        post[key] = value
    }
}
await Post.create(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let post = {
  image: '',
  title: 'hi',
  subtitle: '',
  category: 'Jobs',
  tags: undefined,
  text: null,
  contactperson: '',
  contact: '',
  author: 'Felicia',
  expires: '2022-08-06'
};
let payload ={}
Object.keys(post).filter((key) => !!post[key] && (payload[key] = post[key]));
console.log(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `set` method for Mongoose Schemas:

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    myAttribute: {
      type: String,
      set: (attribute: string) => attribute === '' ? undefined : attribute,
    },
  },
  { strict: 'throw' },
);
```

This will unset the field if the string equals ''.

Use this to trim the strings:
`set: (a: string) => a?.trim() === '' ? undefined : a`